# Generate a formula range from a list of cells

Tags: excel

I'm attempting to aggregate survey results across ~8 workbooks. My strategy was to SUM the numeric responses for each question and divide by the number of non-blank responses. I have 8 workbooks with the same questions but different scores

[image: Example]

In a new book I would attempt this, for example in B5, with a formula like `=SUM(RANGE)/COUNTIF(RANGE,">0")` where RANGE is something like `Book1:B5,Book2:B5,Book3:B5,Book4:B5,Book5:B5,etc`

thus

`=SUM(Book1:B5,Book2:B5,Book3:B5,Book4:B5,Book5:B5)/COUNTIF(Book1:B5,Book2:B5,Book3:B5,Book4:B5,Book5:B5,">0")`

This list approach works fine for SUM formula but not for COUNTIF as it only expects two parameters. Is there a way I can get my list of cells to be interpreted as a range? I tried Define Name but this didn't seem to work for a list either

Comment: Show some sample data for better understanding.

Comment: What does `COUNTIF(RANGE, '>0')` return? Is it possible that `'>0'` should have double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: The problem is that RANGE is actually a list of cells: `COUNTIF(Book1:B5,Book2:B5,Book3:B5,Book4:B5,Book5:B5,'>0')`  this is multiple parameters, where COUNTIF wants just two parameters